# Punctuation of a subtitle starting with "Or"

Tags: punctuation, titles

I have a main title of a chapter: "Eureka!"

My subtitle, right below that, is: "Or, Archimedes in the Bath"

I'm not sure about that comma.

What are common practices? Are there any authoritative rules for how to punctuate a subtitle?

Comment: Subtitles are often separated by colons, but that would be messy here. I've read that on occasion, a smaller font has been successfully used (with no added conjunction). But writing style questions do not fit well with the ELU format.

Comment: Yes, I used a slightly smaller font, and I'm fine with using a carriage return instead of a colon to separate the title and the subtitle.  What I'm not sure about is the comma after "or".

Comment: That's funny, some comments just disappeared.  Anyway, *Pinocchio* wasn't the right book. I remembered right that it has long-winded chapter titles, but there's no "or".  I looked at the original *Pygmalion* and *Frankenstein*, as I think was suggested in one of the comments that I can no longer see.  At Project Gutenberg I found "Frankenstein, (new line) or the Modern Prometheus."  I think my exclamation mark takes the place of the comma after "Frankenstein", so I guess I don't need any commas.

Comment: And I guess I should use the lower case "or".

Comment: @aparente001 Jasper Loy deleted his answer (I presume the examples provided convinced him that such a comma does have historical legitimacy), so the comments to the answer also disappeared.

Comment: Examples of differing style choices are at [mentalfloss](http://mentalfloss.com/article/26015/10-famous-books-lesser-known-subtitles). These also seem authentic: <<Black Beauty: The Autobiography of a Horse>> / << Uncle Tom's Cabin or, Life Among the Lowly>> /  <<Walden, or, Life in the Woods>> / <<Vanity Fair, A Novel without a Hero>> **and** <<Vanity Fair: A Novel without a Hero>> / <<Candide: or, Optimism (1947 translation) >> / << Oliver Twist, or The Parish Boy's Progress>>  **and** <<Oliver Twist or the Parish Boy's Progress>> **and** <<... Oliver Twist, or, The parish boy's progress >>.

Comment: I suppose you might consider the example by the Oxford professor as definitive "The Hobbit, or There and Back Again"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a style issue. *The Chicago Manual of Style* has this to say:

**8.165 *Double titles connected by "or."*** Old-fashioned double titles (or titles and subtitles) connected by *or* are traditionally referred to as in the first [of the following] examples, less traditionally but more simply as in the second. *Chicago* prefers the first form, but either form is acceptable if used consistently.

*England's Monitor; or, The History of the Separation*

*England's Monitor, or The History of the Separation*

Thus, since your punctuation after "Eureka" is already established with the exclamation point:

**Eureka! or, Archimedes in the Bath**

However, no comma is not incorrect. Note that in either example, "or" is lower case.

Answer (score 0):

> Eureka!
>
> or Archimedes in the Bath

I can't seem to center what's in the block quote....

(I'd like to credit whoever suggested looking at *Frankenstein* -- I'm really not sure where those comments went.  One of them was a comment of mine!  And they've disappeared!)

Comment: I'd still like to see the two alternative titles set off somehow from the non-titular 'or' (if you insist on keeping it; modern practice seems largely to be to  drop it). Different fonts and/or font sizes would seem a fairly non-controversial way.

Comment: However, after looking at quite a few examples on the internet, my suspicions that the inclusion or not of a comma after _or_ is an arbitrary style choice rather than something a reasonable person could say has an unequivocal answer have been 99+% confirmed.